# "В контакте"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

Какой предлог правильно употреблать, когда речь идет о социальной сети "в контакте"? Например: "Я прочитал это в (во) "В контакте". Но два раза "в" как-то тоже не звучит...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в данном случае предлог "в" содержится в самом названии "Вконтакте", поэтому это как раз тот исключительный случай (других не знаю), когда предлог "в" не нужен. ИМХО.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, можно подумать, что "В контакте" наречие, определяющее состояние, способ. Сидеть в контакте(вконтакте) - как? находясь в социальной сети Вконтакте, посмотреть в контакте(вконтакте) - где?

Поэтому в языке простого общения, мне кажется, написание "Вконтакте" давно определилось и пишется без дополнительного предлога и более того, раздельно и маленькими буквами.

А вот в деловых бумагах это надо писать по конструкции: в социальной сети "Вконтакте" или на сайте "Вконтакте". Или же через во Вконтакте по подобию написания фразы в самой же социальной сети: "они не имеют ко ВКонтакте никакого отношения". Кстати, кавычки тоже не пишутся. Здесь же вопрос о слитном или раздельном написании отпадает, и обращается внимание на само название владельцами сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то подобные случаи лежат пока за пределами нормативного регулирования. 
По факту - используется без дополнительного предлога: *Я прочитал это "Вконтакте"*.

Answer (score 0):

Второй предлог явно избыточен. И так всем понятно, о чём речь. Вот интересно другое: почему создатели назвали сеть "В контакте", а не "Контакт". Сказались веяния моды коверкать русский язык? Интересно, что другие участники нашего портала думают по этому поводу. Или, может, кто-то знает точный ответ?

Comment: "Почитайте как там народ "контактирует" и каким языком." И всё станет ясно...
аххаха да так все ща абщаюца...  так вот я про моду коверкать русский язык
Это язык СМСок:быстрее набирается и, главное, меньше символов. Причём общающиеся подобным образом молодые люди зачастую прекрасно владеют родным языком: грамотно пишут и говорят.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно писать развернуто и громоздко: "Я прочитал это в [социальной] сети "ВКонтакте"

Отдельный вопрос как писать само название социальной сети правильно - "ВКонтакте", "В контакте", "В Контакте", "вконтакте" или еще как-то. Тем более, что вроде как, это уже торговое название.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос, как поступать с такими названиями. Относительно этой конкретной соцсети я нашел простое решение: пишу **прочитал на VK** или **прочитал на [сайте] vk.com**, благо, VK — это более актуальное и более простое в употреблении название. Но этот трюк, конечно, не решает общей проблемы с названиями, например, в случае с кафе «ВКофейне» или магазином «ВКроватке». Видимо, лучше не опускать существительное, поясняющее, чем занимается организация (*соцсеть*, *кафе*, *магазин* и т. п.): **сижу в кафе «ВКофейне»**.